# Custom template context processor doesn't work

Tags: python, django

So basically I have a template context processor that looks like this :

```
def tests_context(request):
    tests = Test.objects.filter(group=request.user.group)
    users_tests = CompletedTest.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    categories = Category.objects.all()
    categories_tests = {}

    for category in categories:
        categories_tests[category] = Test.objects.filter(category=category).filter(group=request.user.group)

    return {"categories_tests": categories_tests, "users_tests": users_tests}
```

I add this function to my TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.request"
    "tests.views.tests_context",
)
```

And it doesn't work. It doesn't even call this function fucntion. My app is named tests. Why is django not even calling this function ? Could it be because of the app name ? How do I solve it.

Comment: Please show the view you are expecting it to be called from.

Comment: @alecxe restarted server, correct settings are being applied.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm expecting this processor to be called when I open my flatpage.

Comment: Please post your view code.

Comment: @Ben there's no view code. I'm trying to access context in flatpages.